# Turning data frame columns from list to character, causing SQLite error

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am trying to add a dataframe to my database and keep getting an error, I was getting this error at first, and found a suggestion to use tibble.

```
> dbWriteTable(db, "Wines", Wines, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"SQLiteConnection", "character", "tbl_df"’
```

After installing the tibble package, I am now getting this error:

```
> dbWriteTable(db, "Wines", Wines, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'character'
```

Is there something wrong with my dataset that is causing this issue? I've never had any trouble with dbWriteTable() before.

I think part of the problem is that 2 of the columns in the dataframe are lists, and I am not sure how to convert them. I tried unlist, but it removed the column I tried it on from my dataframe. 
The data was obtained from web scraping, so here is a little bit of what I am working with. My data frame has over 1000 rows.

```
Wines <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = 
"Winery Name Year   Price   Rating  Excerpt 'Charles Smith' 'Royal City Syrah'  
'2012'  '140'   '96'    'Green Olive, green stem' 'K Vintners'  'Cattle King Syrah' 
'2012'  '70'    '95'    'cranberry, dried herb, pomegranate' 'K Vintners'   
'Klein Syrah'   '2012'  '70'    '94'    'dark fruit, stemmy herb and olive' 
'Two Vintners'  'Make Haste Cinsault'   '2013'  '20'    '93'    '100% cinsault' 
'K Vintners'    'The Hidden Syrah'  '2012'  '70'    '93'    'fresh and dried herbs' 
'Kerloo'    'Stone Tree Malbec' '2013'  '40'    '93'    'dazzles' 'Bets Family' 
'Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon' '2012'  '135'   '93'    'rare cabernet' 'Kerloo' 
'Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon'    '2013'  '50'    '93'    'high-toned herbs' 
'Effete'    'Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon'   '2012'  '60'    '93'    'klispun and bacchus'")
```

When I run head this is what I get:

```
head(Wines)
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]

 Winery      Name  Year price rating                                                                              excerpt
 <list>    <list> <chr> <chr>  <chr>                                                                                <chr>
1 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2012   140     96                   Green olive, green stem and fresh herb aromas are at the fore, ...
2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2012    70     95 The kirsch, cranberry, dried herb, pomegranate and barrel spice aromas are laser ...
3 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2012    70     94               Brooding dark fruit and stemmy herb and olive aromas lead to rich, ...
4 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2013    20     93              This is a rare, 100% varietal Cinsault from Olsen Vineyard that saw ...
5 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2012    70     93             Opening with aromas of fresh and dried herbs, this wine follows with ...
6 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>  2013    40     93          All varietal coming from two blocks of this vineyard, this wine dazzles ...
```

I really feel all I need to do is convert those columns from list to character, but am not sure how to do it while keeping them in the dataframe

Comment: The `Wines <- read.table(...` gives error for me.  Can you post the dput of the first 6 lines.  Perhaps `Wines[1:2] <- lapply(Wines[1:2], unlist)`

Answer (score 1):

It was a surprisingly simple fix.

```
Wines$Winery <- as.character(Wines$Winery)
Wines$Name <- as.character(Wines$Name)
```

This changed everything in the designated columns into character instead of list.

```
> head(Wines)
Source: local data frame [6 x 6]

      Winery                  Name  Year price rating
       <chr>                 <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1 Charles Smith      Royal City Syrah   2012   140     96
2    K Vintners     Cattle King Syrah   2012    70     95
3    K Vintners           Klein Syrah   2012    70     94
4  Two Vintners   Make Haste Cinsault   2013    20     93
5    K Vintners      The Hidden Syrah   2012    70     93
6        Kerloo     Stone Tree Malbec   2013    40     93
Variables not shown: excerpt <chr>.
```

Once I did this I was successfully able to run dbWriteTable without getting any errors.

```
> dbWriteTable(db, "Wines", Wines, row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)
[1] TRUE
```